# How to compare dmn xml files and show the diff of decision tables

Tags: git-diff, bpmn.io, dmn, redhat-bpm

I would like to know is there any tool is available to compare dmn xml files and show the diff of decision tables.

I want to implement diff viewer for dmn xml files to show the diff of decision table using javascript. It would be greatly helpful if you provide any reference for already available diff viewer applications or any javascript npm plugins or any implementation using any language.

Let's consider below example. If decision table name is changed then I want to show only diff of name instead entire table, because if we change name of the table then the id will change. So it is difficult to find the table once we change the table name.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is Jozef, a quality engineer for the DMN editor on the screenshot. Unfortunately there is currently no plan for a feature you describe in your question. Feel free to create a jira in https://issues.redhat.com/projects/KOGITO/issues